# How to get last message between two users in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on a web app build in laravel. I am displaying the last message of the users. But my query display all messages. Below is my query. Please help me to write laravel friendly query.

```
$id = Auth::id();
echo '<pre>';
$messages = Messages::where('to', $id)->orWhere('from', $id)->get();
print_r($messages);
echo '</pre>';
```

Table structure

[image]

Any solution is appreciated!

Comment: Please read the docs before asking a question here. These are Eloquent basics. you use the function `get()` so you get a collection, if you want to select only one: use `first()`. With a little effort you could have found that yourself, no? Quick tip: lose the `<pre>` echo's and replace `print_r()` with `dump()` or `dd()` (debug and die), something magical will happen to your debug dump.

Answer (score 0):

This will show the last message of the user

```
Messages::where('to', $id)->orWhere('from', $id)->latest()->first()
```

Answer (score -1):

To get the last message, you can use `first()` or `limit(1)`. `first()` replaces `get()` and returns you a Model, unlike `limit()` which returns an array.

See the documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset).

Comment: Hey, i have multiple users in chat, so i need messages of user ids present in table

Comment: @RobinSingh Instead of selecting the messages, select the users and get the last message from the defined relationship with messages.

Comment: This should be a comment by the way, not an answer